# how to send image in pushplugin in BigPictureStyle method?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I am developing a cordova application, I would like to know how to send image in pushplugin like BigPictureStyle as done by flipkart myntra and all ..
there is a pull request https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/498
for the same but how to implement this?
how to send the payload so as to show the image in the notification bar.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Could you please attach some of your code?

Comment: this is the code i used to send the notification https://jsfiddle.net/2d2dd4pe/ this is the edited part as that of the above link https://jsfiddle.net/wsbhj8qu/  and this is used to handle the notification https://jsfiddle.net/dxjg5ko1/

Answer (score 0):

**Install the modified plugin**

1. Clone locally and pull the changes

   - Clone [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) locally

     ```
     git clone https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
     ```
   - Add a remote to the repository where the modifications are

     ```
     git remote add bigpicture-repo https://github.com/ajoyoommen/PushPlugin.git
     ```
   - Then fetch the changes

     ```
     git fetch bigpicture-repo
     ```
   - Merge the changes you just fetched (from the remote) into you `master`

     ```
     git merge bigpicture-repo/master
     ```

   **OR**
2. Directly clone my repository containing the feature

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ajoyoommen/PushPlugin
   ```

---

Uninstall the old plugin

```
cordova plugin remove com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
```

Install the new plugin from your filesystem

```
cordova plugin add /home/myname/Documents/PushPlugin
```

---

**Send messages** from your server to your application. If the payload has `bigPicture` in it, with a URL, that image will be downloaded and displayed in a Big Picture style notification.

Comment: I followed your steps, Still its the image is not appering in the notification bar. The picture shows the payload http://s4.postimg.org/thzyzh9tp/Screenshot_2015_09_21_17_40_19.png and the php code i used to send the push https://jsfiddle.net/h4zewLbk/